# How do I know when application is in the background?

Tags: android

I have an application that is a menu with several options, every option when chosen will lead to a new activity.
I also have music playing in the background using a service. I want my music play continuously no matter what activity is focused.

My problem is:

- If I am NOT override onPause() or onStop(), the music will go fine when I open another activity. BUT when I press home button, music still plays.
- If I DO override onPause() or onStop(), the music will  stop when I press Home button, but it also stops when another activity is opened.

So what should I do now?

Comment: Post your code for onPause() & unstop()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `onPause()` and use a boolean flag.
Set the boolean to `true` if you are launching a new activity. When `onPause()` is called you'll know if it is not `true` then you should stop the music.

```
boolean keepPlaying = false;

protected void onPause() { 
    if(!keepPlaying)
        stopService(new Intent(this, MediaPlayerServices.class)); 
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: I used a flag and set it default value to false.So when onPause is call, if flag is false then I stop the music.  
But when I start a new activity and then go back to menu, the flag's value is now true. When I press Home button, music will still play.  
Another issues is, if I press home button when Im in another activity, music will also keep playing.

Comment: Yes, the code above does not cover every situation, it only gives you the idea. I would set `keepPlaying` to `false` in `onResume()` so that it does not become stale. And you should override `onBackPressed()` to track `keepPlaying` in every child Activity. You will need a flag like this in each of your Activities or you could make _one_ `static` `keepPlaying` flag in your Service.

Comment: Just set `flag` to true before open new activy and set it back to false `onPause()` will do the trick.  I dont get the `static flag` part, can you explain further? Thanks!

Comment: You can make one global flag in your MediaPlayerServices class with `public static boolean KEEP_PLAYING = false` and the access it any time the Service is running from _anywhere_ with `MediaPlayerServices.KEEP_PLAYING`. (Java naming convention mandates global variables have all capital letters.)

Comment: I also found that it need to catch the `onHomePressed()` in every activity to set `flag` back to false so `onDestroy` of services can stop the music.
Thank you!

Comment: `onHomePressed()`? What class is that part of? I forgot about [`onUserLeaveHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29), this method may help you.

Comment: Just found out there is no `onHomePressed()`, haha